# SharePoint Calculated Column - Cannot get Syntax correct

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calculated-columns

I have a calculated column with the following code below.  The "status" columns all have statuses of "Not Started", "In Progress", "Submitted" and "Survey Sent".

I am trying to make it so that if the status is not "Submitted" or "Survey Sent", it's set as "Not Completed", otherwise of they are all in the state of "Survey Sent" or "Submitted" it will return as "Completed".

My issue is that I cannot get the syntax correct to have it work this way; I've tried OR() but I might not be doing it right?  Any help would be appreciated.

**Current Calculated Column**

```
=IF(NOT([Day 1 Status]="Survey Sent"),"Not Completed",
IF(NOT([Week 1 Status]="Survey Sent"),"Not Completed",
IF(NOT([30 Day Status]="Survey Sent"),"Not Completed",
IF(NOT([90 Day Status]="Survey Sent"),"Not Completed",
IF(NOT([6 Month Status]="Survey Sent"),"Not Completed",
IF(NOT([Year 1 Status]="Survey Sent"),"Not Completed","Completed"))))))
```

**What I'm looking for logically**

```
If Day 1 Status is not "Survey Sent" or not "Submitted", then "Not Completed"
If Week 1 Status is not "Survey Sent" or not "Submitted", then "Not Completed"
If 30 Day Status is not "Survey Sent" or not "Submitted", then "Not Completed"
If 90 Day Status is not "Survey Sent" or not "Submitted", then "Not Completed"
If 6 Month Status is not "Survey Sent" or not "Submitted", then "Not Completed"
If Year 1 Status is not "Survey Sent" or not "Submitted", then "Not Completed"
Else then "Completed"
```

Comment: Thoughts anyone?  Hoping to figure this out soon :(

Answer (score 0):

This might be late. But I think I got what you want. I think what you explained is not exactly what you need actually.

> if the status is not "Submitted" or "Survey Sent", it's set as "Not Completed"

This condition is always **TRUE**! Because the status cannot both be "Submitted" **AND** "Survey Sent". So either of the expressions becomes true and the whole expression becomes true because of the **OR**. Instead I guess you mean this:

*If the status is **NOT** "Submitted" **AND NOT** "Survey Sent", it's set as "Not Completed".*

The other ambiguous point in your question is the logical operator you need between different status condition. Ask yourself this question: "Do you need all the status fields to be **neither** Survey Sent **nor** Submitted to set the value to Not Completed? or just one of them **not** being Survey Sent or Submitted is enough for the calculated field to be Not Complete?" if one of them is enough, you need **OR** operator between status conditions, otherwise you will need **AND**.

Again, from the logic I guess that you need either of them **not** to be Survey Sent or Submitted for the overall status to be "Not Completed" in which case you will need **OR** between status conditions. To construct the query in such complicated calculated columns the best way is to use Microsoft Excel as the formulas of the calculated columns are very similar to that of Microsoft Excel's. I used Excel and the final query is:

```
=IF(
OR(
AND([Day 1 Status]<>"Survey Sent",[Day 1 Status]<>"Submitted"),
AND([Week 1 Status]<>"Survey Sent",[Week 1 Status]<>"Submitted"),
AND([30 Day Status]<>"Survey Sent",[30 Day Status]<>"Submitted"),
AND([90 Day Status]<>"Survey Sent",[90 Day Status]<>"Submitted"),
AND([6 Month Status]<>"Survey Sent",[6 Month Status]<>"Submitted"),
AND([Year 1 Status]<>"Survey Sent",[Year 1 Status]<>"Submitted")
),
"Not Completed","Completed")
```

Comment: You can logically simplify the above expression as:
'=IF(
AND(
OR([Day 1 Status]="Survey Sent",[Day 1 Status]="Submitted"),
OR([Week 1 Status]="Survey Sent",[Week 1 Status]="Submitted"),
OR([30 Day Status]="Survey Sent",[30 Day Status]="Submitted"),
OR([90 Day Status]="Survey Sent",[90 Day Status]="Submitted"),
OR([6 Month Status]="Survey Sent",[6 Month Status]="Submitted"),
OR([Year 1 Status]="Survey Sent",[Year 1 Status]="Submitted")
),
"Completed","Not Completed")'